# Put option positive Theta and Moneyness

Tags: put, theta

I am trying to differentiate BS Theta with respect to moneyness ratio of the option, which is S/K or spot/strike. The goal is to use Newton's method to find the highest S/K for which Theta >= 0

5.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& C_{B s}-P_{B S}=S_t-k_e-r(t-t) \\
& \theta_c-\theta_p=K r_e-r(t-t) \\
& \theta_p=\theta_c-k r e^{-r(T-t)} \\
& \text { Let } S / k=x \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
taking derivative of op art $x$ :

1. taking $d / d x$ of $\theta_c$ :
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   & \frac{d}{d x} \theta_c=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot S_t \frac{v}{2 \sqrt{1-t}} e^{-\frac{d_1^2}{2}} \cdot \frac{d}{d x} \frac{d_1{ }^2}{2}-r K e^{-r(t-t)} N\left(d_z\right) \frac{d}{d x} d_z \\
   & \frac{d}{d x}-\frac{d_1{ }^2}{2}=-d_1 \cdot \frac{d}{d x} d_1=-d_1: \frac{d}{d x}\left[\frac{\ln (x)+\left(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}\right] \\
   & =d_1 \cdot\left[\frac{1}{v \sqrt{T-t}} \cdot \frac{1}{x}\right] \\
   & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} d_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\ln (x)-\left(r+\frac{v^2}{2}\right)(T-t)}{v \sqrt{T-t}}\right]=\frac{1}{v \sqrt{T-t}} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \\
   &
   \end{aligned}
   $$

So
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{d}{d x} \theta_p=\frac{-S_t}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{\sigma}{2 \sqrt{T-t}} e^{-\frac{d_1{ }^2}{2}-d_1}\left(\frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{T-t}}\right)-r K e^{-r(T-t)} N\left(d_2\right)\left(\frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{T-t}}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{x v \sqrt{T-t}}\left(\frac{d_1 S t}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{\sigma}{2 \sqrt{T-t}} e^{\left.-\frac{d_1{ }^2}{2}-r K e^{-r(T-t)} N\left(d_2\right)\right)}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
subbing back $x=S / k$

Am I on the right track here ? My plan is to use an initial guess for S/K as 0.5 and then use f(theta) and fprime(theta) in Newton's method to find the zero.

Thank you!